# Sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{2}{(2i +1)(2i+3)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

how can I calculate this:
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{2}{(2i +1)(2i+3)}$$
I don't have seen analysis yet, this is a olympic problem of my country.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this question?

Comment: it's from OBM(Math Brazilian Olympic) 2019 undergraduate level. The answer is 1/3.

Answer (score 2):

$$=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (\frac {1}{2i+1} - \frac{1}{2i+3})$$

So It is $$\frac {1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}......$$

answer is $\frac {1}{3}$

Comment: Thanks to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Find $A,B\in\mathbb R$ s.t. $$\frac{1}{(2i+1)(2i+3)}=\frac{A}{2i+1}+\frac{B}{2i+3}.$$

Comment: Thanks! I'll try for the hint.